# Ajax.ActionLink() Renders Partial View Scripts But JavaScript code does not

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using Kendo Grid in my MVC application. The Grid has a Command column which contains a custom button for Details that Calls a Javascript function that sends an ajax request to server to get a partial view to replace the `#AjaxDiv innerHtml` like below :

```
    function BrandDetailView(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    var brandID = dataItem.PKBrand;

    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("AjaxDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Brand/Details/" + brandID, true);
    xmlhttp.send()
}
```

the Detail partial view contains Kendo DropDownList that generates scripts inside its containing `div` . If I send a request to server Like above these scripts wont work, but if I create a `Ajax.ActionLink()` like below, they will work.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Details", new { id = 2 }, new AjaxOptions() 
{
    UpdateTargetId="AjaxDiv",
    HttpMethod="GET",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace 
})
```

I am stuck with the Detail button on the Grid, any solutions how to render scripts that way?

Comment: do you have script on the partial view?

Comment: @MattBodily No there is no scripts on partial view, kendo dropdownlist adds some script to its containing div.

Comment: do you have a button click event that isn't firing?

Comment: @MattBodily No I don't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a script in the content you add to your page via innerHTML, it is not going to execute, one possible solution would be to derive these script tags and add them again via Javascript to your page so that they execute this time.

Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396/1821461